# What is the difference between TcpClient.Stream.Read and TcpClient.Client.Receive?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I am working with some pretty old network code that receives some basic and minimal information (about 28 bytes) from an embedded device for display in some WPF controls.

I have been messing around with the network code a bit, as the embedded device sometimes misses a message here and there.

On the receiving end, the network loop that has been used is the following:

```
 private void ReadTCPData() {
        var btReadBuffer = new byte[256];
        var nRead = 0;
        while (!bStop) {
            if (stream.CanRead) {
                if (stream.DataAvailable) {
                    try {
                        nRead = stream.Read(btReadBuffer, 0, 256);
                    }
                    catch {
                        _isCommError = true;
                    }
                    ParseData(btReadBuffer, nRead);
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
```

If I replace `nRead = stream.Read(btReadBuffer, 0, 256);` (the stream object is simply `tcpClient.GetStream()` )

with

`nRead = tcpClient.Client.Receive(btReadBuffer, 0, 256, SocketFlags.None);`

I get essentially the exact same behaviour.

Having said that, I'm trying to understand the difference between doing a `stream.Read()` and `client.Receive()`?

Edit:

Hmm I suppose technically this is a duplicate, but the answers are disappointingly lacking detail in the existing question.

Comment: Regarding your disagreement with the duplicate: what kind of answer are you looking for, and what are you going to do with an answer? The answer is _"Technically it doesn't matter which you use, as the one is a mere wrapper for the other"_, as explained in the duplicate. It's not like you have run into a NetworkStream bug, or anything.

Comment: Given that the C# end sometimes misses messages from the sending device, that is an issue in itself, and debugging it is difficult as we have little to no capability of debugging the embedded device itself, just the code on the receiving end. I was simply curious as to the difference between methods of receiving data, and I suppose how these 2 methods differ depending on how the sending device is actually sending the data. Though we don't really know that, it could be doing `stream.Write` or maybe just `Send`

Comment: Like I said and the duplicate also mentions, `NetworkStream.Read()` simply calls `Socket.Read()` on the socket it wraps. You also can't "miss messages" in TCP. So I'm afraid you have a different problem, and I'd suggest you to not try to blame framework code; socket code relying on `Thread.Sleep()` often is a red flag in and of itself. Also, sockets are an abstraction; they don't care about the underlying devices. Perhaps try to analyze somewhat more and pinpoint a more accurately defined piece of code, preferably with example data and data you missed.

Comment: I think you're being a little silly here. "You can't miss messages in TCP" - in what reality? I suppose if we assume network conditions are optimal in 100% of cases, 100% of the time, then I _guess_ that could be true, in some alternate universe. Anyway, no one is trying to blame anyone or anything, I was simply asking a question out of curiosity. You are far too uptight and argumentative. Thanks anyway and good luck.

Comment: I am not trying to be uptight, I am trying to figure out what you're trying to ask exactly and get you further towards an answer. The difference between `Socket.Read()` and `NetworkStream.Read()` is not related at all to your problem, that I can say for sure. And no, it is **impossible** to miss "messages" (TCP also doesn't have messages) in TCP: as soon as a packet is irrecoverably lost, the connection will be closed. I understand my comments and the duplicate don't help, but that's because the question is wrong. So again: formulate a proper problem statement, and someone can help you.

Comment: In addition to the "message/packet miss" discussion: if a packet is lost the endpoint who sent it will try to resend it and wait for confirmation that it actually has been received. So unlike UDP you cannot miss any packets unless the connection is dropped/forcibly closed or your internet connection is lost.